# How does var_dump() work?

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP with PHP for absolute beginners. Following the tutorial in chapter 5 I'm getting some weird errors. I'm trying to output entries in a database. When I load the page I get `"Notice: Undefined index: title in /home/craig/public_html/PHP tutorials/simple blog/index.php on line 42"`

and also:

`Notice: Undefined index: entry in /home/craig/public_html/PHP tutorials/simple blog/index.php on line 43`

now, when I var_dump($e) I get outputted:

`array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(13) "I like Cheese" [0]=> string(13) "I like Cheese" ["entry"]=> string(17) "this is some text" [1]=> string(17) "this is some text" } }`

as far as I can see there are indexes 'title' and 'entry' and the info from the db is being pulled. So, why do I get these undefined index errors?

here's the code from index.php if needed I can paste functions.php as well but as far as I can tell it's working as should.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<?php 
include_once 'inc/functions.inc.php';
include_once 'inc/db.inc.php';

        //open a database connection 
        $db = new PDO(DB_INFO, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        //Determine if an entry ID was passed in the URL
        $id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : NULL;

        // load the entries

    $e = retrieveEntries($db, $id);

    //get the fulldisp flag and remove it from the array
    $fulldisp = array_pop($e);

    //saniteze the entry data
    $e = sanitizeData($e);

    ?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" type="text/css" />
<title> Simple Blog </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Simple Blog Application </h1>
<div id="entries">
    <?php 

    // if the full display flag is set, show the entry
    if($fulldisp==1){
    var_dump($e);
    ?>

    <h2> <?php echo $e['title'] ?></h2>
    <p> <?php echo $e['entry']?></p>
    <p class="backlink">
        <a href="./">Back to Latest Entries</a>
        </p>    

        <?php  
    }//end if statement

    //if the full display flag is 0, format linked entry titles 
    else{
        //loop through each entry
        foreach($e as $entry){
        ?>

        <p> <a href="?id=<?php echo $entry['id']?>">
                <?php echo $entry['title'] ?>
        </a>
        </p>
    <?php   
        } //end the foreach loop
    } // end the else
    ?>  




    <p class="backlink">
        <a href="admin.php">Post a new Entry</a>
        </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get these errors whether there is one item to be displayed or if the loop needs to run to output many. Many thanks for any help!

Comment: just above backlink you try to get the "title" and "entry" elements of the array

Comment: The indexes are not in `$array` according to your `var_dump` output. They're in `$array[0]`. `echo "<pre>" . print_r($array, true) . "</pre>"` is **very** useful if you use HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because $e is a multidimensional array - it is an array of arrays. In your foreach loop, $entry references each child array of the multidimensional array, $e. In the first branch of your conditional statement, you are referencing the multidimensional array $e when you are really wanting to reference the first array in $e.

Try this instead:

```
if($fulldisp==1){


   $entry=$e[0]; //$entry is now referencing the first entry in $e rather than $e itself
    ?>

    <h2> <?php echo $entry['title'] ?></h2>
    <p> <?php echo $entry['entry']?></p>
    <p class="backlink">
        <a href="./">Back to Latest Entries</a>
        </p>    

        <?php  
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$entry = $e[0]` be just as, if not even more effective than `array_shift()`?

Comment: array(0) { } this is now the output of the var_dump directly after I added the line $entry=array_shift($e); still the undefined index problem.

Comment: My initial code was removing the first entry from $e and storing it in $entry. I have changed the code so that $e is no longer modified. What you'll want to do now though is var_dump on $entry instead of $e.

Comment: ok, now a single entry will show, (thanks)!! but I tried the same with the output of a list of entries and I don't get any output.